# blueprint css issues not working in ie

Tags: css, blueprint-css

i wanted to try out blueprint and worked just fine from at the beginning then i put the website online and to my surprise nothing worked in ie? is there any css guru that could guide me on what i've might have done wrong here?

http://kurdiskainstitutet.se/

as i said works perfect on everyother browser but internet explorer

Comment: Please elaborate on the IE issues.

Comment: http://browsershots.org/http://kurdiskainstitutet.se/ here you got a better sample of the diffrence, its like the blueprint css file isnt there

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can run Google searches for you ... These posts may help:

[Post #1](http://groups.google.com/group/blueprintcss/browse_thread/thread/0a284fbd8bca6f64)  and   [Post #2](http://groups.google.com/group/blueprintcss/browse_thread/thread/7476d6d311d10d03)

Comment: Sorry.  Since answer is not helpful, down-vote it please.  I can't vote on my own.